# Segfault with smartpointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm currently trying to play with smart pointers and i'm stuck getting a segfault while trying to access getColor() ?

Is somebody able to tell what I'm missing ?
( for comprehension board is defined as following : std::unique_ptr board [HEIGHT][WIDTH]; )

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Piece> current (new Pawn(Color::WHITE));
this->board[1][1] = std::move(current);
        
if(this->board[1][1].get() == nullptr){
    Log::debug("is nullptr");
    return;
}

if(this->board[1][1].get()->getColor() == Color::BLACK){
    Log::debug("Black");
} else{
    Log::debug("White");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  There's not enough here to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not provide many details. But I was able to code it up and run it without a segfault.

https://godbolt.org/z/5Ehfe7

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <fmt/core.h>

constexpr std::size_t HEIGHT {8};
constexpr std::size_t WIDTH {8};

enum class Color {
    WHITE, BLACK
};

struct Piece {
    explicit Piece(Color color) : color_(color) {}
     Color getColor() const {
        return color_;
    }
        Color color_;
};
struct Pawn : public Piece {
    explicit Pawn(Color color) : Piece(color){

    }
};

struct Board {
std::unique_ptr<Piece> board [HEIGHT][WIDTH];
  void set() {
    std::unique_ptr<Piece> current(new Pawn(Color::WHITE));
    this->board[1][1] = std::move(current);

    if (this->board[1][1].get() == nullptr) {
      fmt::print("is nullptr");
      return;
    }

    if (this->board[1][1].get()->getColor() == Color::BLACK) {
      fmt::print("Black");
    } else {
      fmt::print("White");
    }
  }
};

int main() {
    Board b;
    b.set();
}
```

## Update

Here's a version, that I like better: https://godbolt.org/z/z6rfav

### Variant vs Inheritance

Instead of inheritance of `Piece`, I make `PieceType` a `std::variant` over all possible types of pieces (Pawn, Queen, King, ...). This is possible because the set of pieces is closed: we know all possible pieces at compile time.

```cpp
enum class Color { WHITE, BLACK };

struct Pawn {};
struct King {};

using PieceType = std::variant<Pawn, King>;  // extend to all pieces

struct Piece {
  Piece(PieceType type, Color color) : color_(color), type_(type) {}
  Color getColor() const { return color_; }
  Color color_;
  PieceType type_;
};
```

### `std::array` vs unsafe C-Arrays

I switched the definition of `board` from `std::unique_ptr<Piece> board[8][8]` to `std::array<std::array<Piece, 8>, 8>`. This is much safer, and more idiomatic C++.

### Null pointers vs Optional

Instead of using a unique_ptr to signify if a field is empty. I use `std::optional`.

```cpp
  std::array<std::array<std::optional<Piece>, WIDTH>, HEIGHT> board_;

// Could be written as 
using Field = std::optional<Piece>;
using Row = std::array<Field, WIDTH>;
using Board = std::array<Row, HEIGHT>;
Board board_;
```